# Removed class when click outside div but keep removed when div is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div which open when I click on the question mark icon (upper right of the document).
When clicked I add a class which transform the question mark icon in close icon.
When I click outside the div, the div closed and the class is removed, closed icon becomes the question mark icon.
But now when I click in the document, it add and removed the class whenever the div is open or closed.

If anybody have an idea how I can removed the class when cliked on the document only when the div is open.
Thanks

```
jQuery('.showmenu').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      jQuery('.about-btn').toggleClass( "active");
      jQuery('.about').slideToggle('fast');
  });

jQuery('.about').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});

jQuery(document).click(function(){
jQuery('.about-btn').toggleClass( "active");
   jQuery('.about').slideUp('fast');
});
```

Comment: Can you also add your html?

Comment: and css for used classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO 
add/bind `$(document).click` only when/on `$('.showmenu').click` function. 
Later do `$(document).unbind('click')` in `$(document).click` function

ex:

```
$('.showmenu').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $('.about-btn').toggleClass("active");
        $('.about').slideToggle('fast');

        //Binding click function on document
        $(document).click(function () {
            $('.about-btn').toggleClass("active");
            $('.about').slideUp('fast');

            $(document).unbind('click'); //Unbind click
        });

    });

$('.about').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only remove the class `active` instead of toggling it:

```
jQuery(document).click(function(){
   jQuery('.about-btn').removeClass( "active");
   jQuery('.about').slideUp('fast');
});
```

If i understood correctly, you never need to set the class `active` when clicking outside the div, so it should do the trick

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My explanation was a bit messy sorry

Answer (score 0):

Instead of registering the click event to `document`, you could have an overlay under the popup div that appears together and have the close event register on that instead.

---

Or you could also store the state in a variable like so:

```
var isOpen = false;
jQuery('.showmenu').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  jQuery('.about-btn').toggleClass( "active");
  jQuery('.about').slideToggle('fast');
  isOpen = true;
});

jQuery('.about').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});

jQuery(document).click(function(){
  if(!isOpen) return; // early return if not opened
  jQuery('.about-btn').toggleClass( "active");
 jQuery('.about').slideUp('fast');
});
```